# Apply function to dataframe column based on criteria of a different dataframe while ensuring no duplicates

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes:

```
data = [[10],[10],[10],[20],[20],[20],[30],[30],[30]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Number'])

nameList=[['grant',10],['grant',10],['grant',10],['grant',10],['greg',10],['thom',10],['amy',20],['steve',20],['sally',20],['ralph',30],['olive',30],['bobb',30]]
nameDF = pd.DataFrame(nameList, columns=['Name','Number'])
```

I want to create a new column based on a random choice of Name from nameDF with criteria of Number=Number. I do not want duplicates.

I tried creating a function and using apply but could not figure out how to apply function again if random choice name was already in new column. I am not sure if this is the right approach to go about this problem. Please help!

```
def random_word(num):
    numDF = nameDF[nameDF['Number']==num]
    return np.random.choice(numDF['Name'],1)

df['New_Name'] = df['Number'].apply(random_word)
```

Comment: can you put your expected output as text as well?

Comment: Variable and function names should follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style.

Comment: thanks for the tip @AMC ! Still learning python :]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Will this work for you?
I just added 3-4 lines to your code. Created 2 lists(lst, lst2) and kept on appending the values to lst2 which were already chosen. Before choosing the random name and returning the value for the New_Name column it will check if the value does **not** exist in lst2 to avoid duplicate names in the final df.

```
def random_word(num):
    numDF = nameDF[nameDF['Number']==num]
    global lst
    lst = numDF['Name'].tolist()
    x = np.random.choice([i for i in lst if i not in lst2],1)[0]
    lst2.append(x)
    return x
global lst2
lst2 =[]
df['New_Name'] = df['Number'].apply(random_word)
df
```

[image]

Comment: @gucher Please accept the answer if this is what you were looking for. :)

Comment: sorry! First time posting a question to stackoverflow. Thanks!